# How to add templates.xml using plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Editor templates in eclipse can be imported from xml file. Instead of manually importing, wanted to create a plugin. Which will import the templates.xml kept in specified folder at start of the eclipse.
How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JFace `org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.persistence.TemplateReaderWriter` to read a template.xml. Something like:

```java
File file = .... file to read

TemplateReaderWriter reader = new TemplateReaderWriter();
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
TemplatePersistenceData[] datas = reader.read(input, null);
```

(code to deal with errors and closing the input left out)

You can then put the data in a `TemplateStore`:

```java
TemplateStore fTemplateStore = ... store to use

for (TemplatePersistenceData data: datas) {                 
   fTemplateStore.add(data);
}

fTemplateStore.save();
```

The template store you use depends on which templates you are updating.

For the Java Editor template store you can get the store with

```java
JavaPlugin.getDefault().getTemplateStore();
```

**But** the `JavaPlugin` is not part of the official Eclipse API.

The above code is a simplified version of the import code in  `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.templates.TemplatePreferencePage`